# How did people (Read Physicists) come to the conclusion that entropy will be exhausted

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Every once in a while on the Internet I read stuff like. 'There is a limit to entropy of universe', 'Entropy of Universe will be exhausted' etc. etc. What intrigues me is that:

1. Is it real. How can you ever run out of randomness?
2. If it is ? How did people come to the conclusion that such a thing is plausible

Comment: $\uparrow$ Read where? Reference and/or link?

Comment: A lot of forums and sometimes Quora

Comment: The observable universe is finite in size and therefore there's only a finite number of microstates (and hence a limit). The exhaustion then follows from the second law of thermodynamics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine adding some coffee to a cup of milk. At first the coffee is separated from the milk and we know the exact position of the coffee particles and the milk particles. This is a minimum entropy state. But wait a little bit and you can see that the coffee starts mixing with the milk and you can't tell for sure where are the coffee particles. This lack of knowledge or randomness is an increase in entropy. Then if you wait for a while, you will notice that coffee and milk are completely mixed up and nothing is changing anymore. This is what we call equilibrium and at this stage the entropy is maximum.

We deal with the universe on a similar bases. Looking at the expansion of the stars and galaxies, physicists calculated the entropy of the observable universe and found it to be increasing since the big bang and are afraid of a maximum entropy where everything becomes in a complete equilibrium and cool down to 0 °k.

Comment: Entropy is not a measure of lack of knowledge . One possibly knows all the configurations possible for the system  . The choice of configuration is what that is probable (not certain).